# Update images in canvas input type file jCanvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, jcanvas

Im using jCanvas to make flyer editor with jQuery : https://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/

```js
$(function () {
  initCanvas();

  $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
    closeText: 'Fermer',
    prevText: '<Préc',
    nextText: 'Suiv>',
    currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
    monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Aout', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Avr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aou', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Di', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Me', 'Je', 'Ve', 'Sa'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+12M +0D',
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true
  };

  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
  $("#date_input").on("change", function () {
    $(this).css("color", "rgba(0,0,0,0)").siblings(".datepicker_label").css({
      "text-align": "center",
      position: "absolute",
      left: "140px",
      top: "40px",
      width: $(this).width()
    }).text($(this).val().length == 0 ? "" : ($.datepicker.formatDate($(this).attr("dateformat"), new Date($(this).val()))));
  });

  $('form').on('keyup change paste', 'input, select, textarea', function () {
    console.log("hola datevid");
    updateCanvasTEXT();
  });

  $('#pic_broadcaster').on("change", function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
        updateCanvasIMG(e.target.result, '');
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });

  $('#pic_challenger').on("change", function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
        updateCanvasIMG('', e.target.result);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
});

function updateCanvasIMG(pic_broadcaster = "", pic_challenger = "") {
  if (pic_broadcaster.indexOf('data:') !== -1) {
    console.log('pic_broadcaster contains data:');
  } else {
    console.log('pic_broadcaster not contains data:');
  }

  $('#canvas').setLayer('photo_bc', {
    type: 'image',
    source: pic_broadcaster,
    x: 42,
    y: 332,
    width: 334,
    height: 334,
    fromCenter: false
  }).setLayer('photo_challenger', {
    type: 'image',
    source: pic_challenger,
    x: 625,
    y: 332,
    width: 334,
    height: 334,
    fromCenter: false
  }).setLayer('fond_canvas', {
    type: 'image',
    source: 'https://i.ibb.co/FwkgQ2n/fond.png',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000,
    fromCenter: false
  }).drawLayers();
}

function updateCanvasTEXT() {
  $('#canvas').setLayer('pseudo_bc', {
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    x: 150,
    y: 715,
    fontSize: 35,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    maxWidth: 300,
    align: 'left',
    respectAlign: true,
    text: $('#bc_agency').val()
  }).setLayer('pseudo_challenger', { // pseudo challenger
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    x: 710,
    y: 715,
    fontSize: 35,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    maxWidth: 300,
    align: 'left',
    respectAlign: true,
    text: $('#bc_challenger').val()
  }).setLayer('date_time', { // date et heure
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    fontStyle: 'bold',
    x: 500,
    y: 820,
    fontSize: 45,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    text: $('.datepicker_label').text() + " à " + $('.event_heure').val().replace(":", "h")
  }).drawLayers();
}

function initCanvas() {
  $('#canvas').addLayer({ // photo bc
    name: 'photo_bc',
    type: 'image',
    source: "",
    x: 42,
    y: 332,
    width: 334,
    height: 334,
    fromCenter: false
  }).addLayer({ // photo adversaire
    name: 'photo_challenger',
    type: 'image',
    source: "",
    x: 625,
    y: 332,
    width: 334,
    height: 334,
    fromCenter: false
  }).addLayer({ // fond
    name: 'fond_canvas',
    type: 'image',
    source: '',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000,
    fromCenter: false
  }).addLayer({ // pseudo bc 
    name: 'pseudo_bc',
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    x: 150,
    y: 715,
    fontSize: 35,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    maxWidth: 300,
    align: 'left',
    respectAlign: true,
    text: $('#bc_agency').val()
  }).addLayer({ // pseudo challenger
    name: 'pseudo_challenger',
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    x: 710,
    y: 715,
    fontSize: 35,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    maxWidth: 300,
    align: 'left',
    respectAlign: true,
    text: $('#bc_challenger').val()
  }).addLayer({ // date et heure
    name: 'date_time',
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    fontStyle: 'bold',
    x: 500,
    y: 820,
    fontSize: 45,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    text: $('.datepicker_label').text() + " à " + $('.event_heure').val().replace(":", "h")
  }).drawLayers();
}
```

```css
.canvas{width: 97vw;height: 60vh;max-width: 1000px;max-height: 1000px;}
#date_input{text-indent: -500px;height:25px; width:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/jcanvas.15.12.12.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="bc_agency" for="input">Pseudo broadcaster: </label>
  <input type="text" name="bc_agency" id="bc_agency" placeholder="Entrer votre pseudo" value="Pseudo">
  <label class="bc_challenger" for="input">Pseudo advsersaire: </label>
  <input type="text" name="bc_challenger" id="bc_challenger" placeholder="Entrer le pseudo de l'adversaire" value="Pseudo"><br>
  Date de l'évévement <input type="date" name="pk_date" dateformat="DD d MM" id="date_input"><span class="datepicker_label" style="pointer-events: none;"></span> Heure <input type="time" name="event_heure" class="event_heure"><br>
  Photo broadcaster: <input type="file" name="pic_broadcaster" id="pic_broadcaster"><br>
  Photo adversaire: <input type="file" name="pic_challenger" id="pic_challenger"><br>
</form>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000">
  <p>This is fallback content for users of assistive technologies or of browsers that don't have full support for the Canvas API.</p>
</canvas>
```

In my javascript, first i call my function initCanvas() to add layers to the canvas and it work well when the page load.

As you can see in my demo, you can change text, date and time but when you want to change images with setLayer() function, the background and everything run away...

I tryed for many hours but it still dont work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In you current code you where sending only one value in `updateCanvasIMG` so the other value was returning null and was not loading image.Instead in below code i have declare 2 variable to save value of `pic_broadcaster` and `pic_challenger` and have check if the value is not empty .If the value are empty for another file send default image url to your function `updateCanvasIMG`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(function() {
  initCanvas();

  $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
    closeText: 'Fermer',
    prevText: '<Préc',
    nextText: 'Suiv>',
    currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
    monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Aout', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Avr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aou', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Di', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Me', 'Je', 'Ve', 'Sa'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+12M +0D',
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true
  };

  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
  $("#date_input").on("change", function() {
    $(this).css("color", "rgba(0,0,0,0)").siblings(".datepicker_label").css({
      "text-align": "center",
      position: "absolute",
      left: "140px",
      top: "40px",
      width: $(this).width()
    }).text($(this).val().length == 0 ? "" : ($.datepicker.formatDate($(this).attr("dateformat"), new Date($(this).val()))));
  });

  $('form').on('keyup change paste', 'input, select, textarea', function() {
    console.log("hola datevid");
    updateCanvasTEXT();
  });
  var file1 = "";
  var file2 = "";

  $('#pic_broadcaster').on("change", function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
        file1 = e.target.result;
        //checking if file2 is not null
        if (file2 != "") {
        //send same
          updateCanvasIMG(file1, file2);
        } else {
        //send default image
          updateCanvasIMG(file1, "https://i.ibb.co/hHDj50p/S-3629060.jpg");
        }
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }

  });


  $('#pic_challenger').on("change", function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
        file2 = e.target.result;
  //check if file1 is not null 
        if (file1 != "") {
        //send same to function
          updateCanvasIMG(file1, file2);
        } else {
        //send default image
          updateCanvasIMG("https://i.ibb.co/qNP921b/IMG-0146.jpg", file2);
        }
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
});

function updateCanvasIMG(pic_broadcaster, pic_challenger) {

  $('#canvas').setLayer('photo_bc', {
    type: 'image',
    source: pic_broadcaster,
    x: 42,
    y: 332,
    width: 334,
    height: 334,
    fromCenter: false
  }).setLayer('photo_challenger', {
    type: 'image',
    source: pic_challenger,
    x: 625,
    y: 332,
    width: 334,
    height: 334,
    fromCenter: false
  }).setLayer('fond_canvas', {
    type: 'image',
    source: 'https://i.ibb.co/FwkgQ2n/fond.png',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000,
    fromCenter: false
  }).drawLayers();
}

function updateCanvasTEXT() {
  $('#canvas').setLayer('pseudo_bc', {
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    x: 150,
    y: 715,
    fontSize: 35,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    maxWidth: 300,
    align: 'left',
    respectAlign: true,
    text: $('#bc_agency').val()
  }).setLayer('pseudo_challenger', { // pseudo challenger
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    x: 710,
    y: 715,
    fontSize: 35,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    maxWidth: 300,
    align: 'left',
    respectAlign: true,
    text: $('#bc_challenger').val()
  }).setLayer('date_time', { // date et heure
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    fontStyle: 'bold',
    x: 500,
    y: 820,
    fontSize: 45,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    text: $('.datepicker_label').text() + " à " + $('.event_heure').val().replace(":", "h")
  }).drawLayers();
}

function initCanvas() {
  $('#canvas').addLayer({ // photo bc
    name: 'photo_bc',
    type: 'image',
    source: "https://i.ibb.co/qNP921b/IMG-0146.jpg",
    x: 42,
    y: 332,
    width: 334,
    height: 334,
    fromCenter: false
  }).addLayer({ // photo adversaire
    name: 'photo_challenger',
    type: 'image',
    source: "https://i.ibb.co/hHDj50p/S-3629060.jpg",
    x: 625,
    y: 332,
    width: 334,
    height: 334,
    fromCenter: false
  }).addLayer({ // fond
    name: 'fond_canvas',
    type: 'image',
    source: 'https://i.ibb.co/FwkgQ2n/fond.png',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000,
    fromCenter: false
  }).addLayer({ // pseudo bc 
    name: 'pseudo_bc',
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    x: 150,
    y: 715,
    fontSize: 35,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    maxWidth: 300,
    align: 'left',
    respectAlign: true,
    text: $('#bc_agency').val()
  }).addLayer({ // pseudo challenger
    name: 'pseudo_challenger',
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    x: 710,
    y: 715,
    fontSize: 35,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    maxWidth: 300,
    align: 'left',
    respectAlign: true,
    text: $('#bc_challenger').val()
  }).addLayer({ // date et heure
    name: 'date_time',
    type: 'text',
    fillStyle: '#fff',
    fontStyle: 'bold',
    x: 500,
    y: 820,
    fontSize: 45,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    text: $('.datepicker_label').text() + " à " + $('.event_heure').val().replace(":", "h")
  }).drawLayers();
}
```

```css
.canvas {
  width: 97vw;
  height: 60vh;
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

#date_input {
  text-indent: -500px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/jcanvas.15.12.12.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="bc_agency" for="input">Pseudo broadcaster: </label>
  <input type="text" name="bc_agency" id="bc_agency" placeholder="Entrer votre pseudo" value="Pseudo">
  <label class="bc_challenger" for="input">Pseudo advsersaire: </label>
  <input type="text" name="bc_challenger" id="bc_challenger" placeholder="Entrer le pseudo de l'adversaire" value="Pseudo"><br> Date de l'évévement <input type="date" name="pk_date" dateformat="DD d MM" id="date_input"><span class="datepicker_label" style="pointer-events: none;"></span>  Heure <input type="time" name="event_heure" class="event_heure"><br> Photo broadcaster: <input type="file" name="pic_broadcaster" id="pic_broadcaster"><br> Photo adversaire: <input type="file" name="pic_challenger" id="pic_challenger"><br>
</form>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000">
  <p>This is fallback content for users of assistive technologies or of browsers that don't have full support for the Canvas API.</p>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your time and your explanations